# Delegate of UITextField not being called using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I was trying to handle user input using `UITextField` which I implemented its delegate function.

This is variable which I drag from storyboard to my viewController

```
class DailPadViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

 @IBOutlet weak var numberTextField: UITextField!
```

This is delegate I called in viewDidload()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    PermissionAppUser.AskAudioPermission()
    numberTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    numberTextField.delegate = self

    customizeBtnStyle()

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(deletedAll))
    delete.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}
```

This delegate that I implemented it but it never call...

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("Text begin editing")
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    return updatedText.count <= 9
}
```

Edit: Add function viewDidload

Comment: add a breakpoint at `numberTextField.delegate = self` and check what is the value of numberTextField

Comment: check connection of numberTextField from storyboard

Comment: @sanjaykmwt, PramosShukla if there was any problem with connection of IBOutlet app would crash with an error says found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Comment: @sanjaykmwt the value is numberTextField correctly sir!

Comment: @PramodShukla they are connected

Comment: Did you try to set the delegate directly from the storyboard and not in viewDidLoad??

Comment: can you provide your actual `viewDidLoad` method impl. since you have a typo in your post?

Comment: @FrancescoDestino i also tried to set delegate from stroyboard but it still not work properly....

Comment: @PeterPajchl I added it. Please check it out

Comment: numberTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false. That's says it all. Delete that line

Comment: @FrancescoDestino oh! But what if don't want to keyboard to pop up on screen because actually i am building a dialpad that's why i put isUserInteractionEnable method.

Comment: Look my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to show the keyboard use this code

```
numberTextField.inputView = UIView()
```